# Image width from image address in jquery

Tags: jquery

how would i get a image width using only the image link in jquery?
can someone lead me down the right path please

Thank You,

Comment: Yeah, it's real easy, you implement something like $("#YourPost").add("more details, what are you asking us?");

Comment: I'd do an ajax call to a PHP script calculating that and sending back the value.

Comment: @user257493 I think the question is pretty clear.

Comment: I made the comment when the post was 51 seconds old, He's edited the question since to be more coherent. It was something like "How do I use link tag to get image with jquery?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using JavaScript, but only in an asynchronous manner, because the image would need to be downloaded before you could access its width:

```
function getImgSize(src, callback) { 
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = function () { callback(this.width, this.height); }
}
```

Example usage

```
getImgSize("http://www.google.co.uk/logos/classicplus.png", function (w, h) {
    alert(w);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://your.host.here/your.image.file.png";
img.onload = function() {
  alert(this.width);
};
```

Comment: Requires that the entire image be downloaded only to get it's width, but there is really no other way with pure JavaScript.

Comment: Well yes that's true; until somebody cooks up a $.psychic() plugin for jQuery we're kind of stuck with that :-)

Comment: I was tempted to down vote two of your answers so that we would have *exactly* the same rep.  I decided to go the other way though and up vote this one :-P +1

Comment: @Andy thanks!!  I'm about to have a whole bunch of real work to do so you'll probably pass me again :-)